# How do I change asciidoctor quote block substitution from normal to verbatim?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

```
= Quote Block Example
:icon: font

This example is used to illustrate a use case for callouts within quote blocks and engage the asciidoctor community in providing an answer for how to accomplish that. The question is how does one change the substitution method for quote blocks from "normal" to "verbatim"?

== Example Quote Block With Attempted Callouts

[quote,The Declaration of Independence,subs="verbatim,attributes"]
____
When in the Course of human events it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the *Laws of Nature and of Nature's God* <1>
entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.

We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and *the pursuit of Happiness*. <2>
— That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed, — That whenever any Form of Government becomes destructive of these ends, it is the Right of the People to alter or to abolish it, and to institute new Government, laying its foundation on such principles and organizing its powers in such form, as to them shall seem most likely to effect their Safety and Happiness.
____
<1> Implies the founders believed in link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_law[Natural law]
<2> The current American cultural conception of "Happiness" link:http://www.patheos.com/blogs/mercynotsacrifice/2013/07/05/property-and-the-pursuit-of-happiness/[tends more toward self-centeredness] which doesn't lead to true happiness at all.
```

When running an asciidoctor conversion of the source code above, the callouts inside the quote block fail to render while the callouts after the quote block are rendered as expected. Command line output returns the following errors:

```
$ asciidoctor quote_block_callouts.adoc
asciidoctor: WARNING: quote_block_callouts.adoc: line 16: no callout found for <1>
asciidoctor: WARNING: quote_block_callouts.adoc: line 17: no callout found for <2>
```

This behavior is expected since it's consistent with the substitution modes documented in the [Building blocks in AsciiDocs](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-writers-guide/#building-blocks-in-asciidoc) section of the AsciiDoc Writer's Guide at asciidoctor.org, but as you can see I was hoping passing the subs="verbatim,attributes" argument to the quote block might provide the solution I need. I've done a fair amount of research into how I could change the substitution mode for quote blocks but haven't found any articles describing how to go about doing that. I did see a reference somewhere, though I can't remember where, that said this could be accomplished within the asciidoctor configuration file.

Thanks in advance for any help the asciidoctor community can provide in finding a solution to this problem.

Comment: I would rather not do it this way, but the desired effect could be achieved by substituting <1> and <2> in the quote block with pass:[<i class="conum" data-value="1"></i><b>(1)</b>] and pass:[<i class="conum" data-value="2"></i><b>(2)</b>]

Comment: Another good reason why I wouldn't want to use the solution I've outlined in my previous update to this question is that while it's a viable workaround for conversion to HTML5, it completely breaks PDF generation.

Comment: Callouts work on a line-by-line basis, which you simply don't have in a quote. Hence, there is no place to properly put the callout link.

Comment: What you want appears to be footnotes, not callouts.